# Find rows in B not in A

Tags: arrays, matlab, member

Matrix A(100,3) and B(1000,3). I want to obtain 1) rows in B that are not in A with their indices, 2) rows in B & present in A with their indices.

```
A=randi([1 5],100,3)
B=randi([1 5],1000,3)
[a b]=intersect(A,B)
[c d]=~intersect(A,B)
```

How to put it so that row indices will be obtained.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`setdiff`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setdiff.html) and [`intersect`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/intersect.html) with the `'rows'` option:

```
[inBnotA, inBnotAindex] = setdiff(B, A, 'rows');
[inBandA, inBandAindex] = intersect(B, A, 'rows');
```

Comment: [`setxor`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setxor.html) is another function with similar applications (opposite of `intersect`).